# TIMESTAMPDIFF SQL

Tags: sql

tengo una tabla de 'controlHoras' donde tengo los campos 'HoraEntrada', 'HoraSalida' que guardan la fecha y hora con este formato '2021/01/16 20:00' a través de un formulario.

Lo que quiero es que a final de mes se pueda realizar un control de todas las horas trabajadas para calcular el precio/hora.

Actualmente empleo la siguiente instrucción `SELECT TIMESTAMPDIFF(hour, '2021/01/15 16:00', '2021/01/15 20:00' ) AS 'Horas Trabajadas'`

Con lo anterior, como es obvio, solo consigo que me devuelva las horas trabajadas de ese intervalo temporal, pero la tabla tiene treinta filas (correspondientes a cada día del mes) y varios trabajadores.

¿alguna idea de cómo puedo calcular las horas trabajadas?

edito: esta es la estructura de la tabla. Solo tiene una FK que es IdTrabajador que enlaza con otra tabla donde están todos los trabajadores.

```
Field       Type      Null      Key   Default   Extra
Id          int(10)     NO      PRI   NULL      auto_increment
HoraEntrada datetime    NO            NULL  
HoraSalida  datetime    NO            NULL  
IdTrabajadorint(10)     NO      MUL   NULL  
Remarks     varchar(100)YES           NULL
```

La consulta que he llegado a realizar es

```
SELECT CONCAT( "trabajadores"."Nombre", ' ', "trabajadores"."Apellido1" ) "trabajadores",TIMESTAMPDIFF(hour,'controlHoras.HoraEntrada', 'controlHoras.HoraSalida' ) AS 'Horas Trabajadas' , "controlHoras"."horaEntrada","controlHoras"."horaSalida","controlHoras"."Remarks" "Remarks" 
FROM "empresa"."controlHoras" "controlHoras", "empresa"."trabajadores" "trabajadores" 
WHERE "controlHoras"."Idtrabajador" = "trabajadores"."Idtrabajador";
```

Con dicha consulta me devuelve todas las filas con registros pero no calcula el campo 'Horas Trabajadas'

Comment: necesitas usar un lenguaje de programación en el backend para calcular el tiempo de trabajo de cada día; tu pregunta pone en contexto como guardas la información y como encuentras parte de la informacion... pero se requieren mas detalles: la estructura completa de la tabla y el código en el backend  que procesa los datos.

Comment: pon la estructura de tus tablas para poderte ayudar

Comment: Field       Type      Null      Key   Default   Extra
Id          int(10)     NO      PRI   NULL      auto_increment
HoraEntrada datetime    NO            NULL  
HoraSalida  datetime    NO            NULL  
IdTrabajadorint(10)     NO      MUL   NULL  
Remarks     varchar(100)YES           NULL

Comment: A ver así no se entiende nada,  edita tu pregunta y pon el diagrama de tus tablas ahi

Comment: finalmente he encontrado la solución. Simplemente quitar las comillas simples de la función `TIMESTAMPDIFF(hour, controlHoras.HoraEntrada, controlHoras.HoraSalida ) AS 'Horas Trabajadas'` 
Ahora al realizar la consulta salen todos los registros con un campo denominado 'Horas Trabajadas' en el que calcula las horas trabajadas de cada trabajador.

Answer (score 0):

Para realizar la consulta deberías obtener todos los valores del "las horas trabajadas" (aquí un paréntesis, porque te recomendaría que obtener los minutos calculados, pero bueno depende del negocio de tu aplicación) y allí con los valores de las horas (o minutos) realizar las agrupaciones correspondientes

Te dejo un ejemplo online para que lo pruebes

- [Ejemplo 1: Consulta agrupada con subconsultas de las horas trabajo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!18/33154/4/1) lo puedes probar online, con el enlace pero dejo el codigo del sql

  ```
    SELECT 
           TEMP.IdTrabajador,
           TrabajadasTrabajadasEnHoras = SUM(TEMP.TrabajadasTrabajadasEnHoras),
           TrabajadasTrabajadasEnMinutos = SUM(TEMP.TrabajadasTrabajadasEnMinutos)
    FROM (
           SELECT
               CH.IdTrabajador,
           TrabajadasTrabajadasEnHoras = DATEDIFF(HOUR, CH.HoraEntrada, CH.HoraSalida),
               TrabajadasTrabajadasEnMinutos = DATEDIFF(MINUTE, CH.HoraEntrada, CH.HoraSalida)
           FROM dbo.ControlHoras CH
         --WHERE Aqui iria el filtro de rango de fecha
    ) TEMP
   GROUP BY TEMP.IdTrabajador

    GO
  ```
- [Ejemplo 2Consulta con CTE para obtener las horas trabajadas](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!18/33154/6/0)

  ```
    ;WITH HorasTrabajadasCTE
        AS(
            SELECT
                CH.IdTrabajador,
                TrabajadasTrabajadasEnHoras = DATEDIFF(HOUR, CH.HoraEntrada, CH.HoraSalida),
                TrabajadasTrabajadasEnMinutos = DATEDIFF(MINUTE, CH.HoraEntrada, CH.HoraSalida)
            FROM dbo.ControlHoras CH
        )


        SELECT 
            CTE.IdTrabajador,
            TrabajadasTrabajadasEnHoras = SUM(CTE.TrabajadasTrabajadasEnHoras),
            TrabajadasTrabajadasEnMinutos = SUM(CTE.TrabajadasTrabajadasEnMinutos)
        FROM HorasTrabajadasCTE CTE
        GROUP BY CTE.IdTrabajador
  ```

Luego puedes modificarlo para agregar los inner join necesarios (con los datos de los trabajadores, etc)

Enlaces que te pueden ayudar

- [SELECT - GROUP BY- Transact-SQL](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/queries/select-group-by-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver15)

Espero que te sirva a ayuda o guía

Comment: Gracias Jose por tu respuesta. Comentarte que he tratado de implementar tu solución pero siempre obtengo el siguiente mensaje de error: 'Error Code: 1054. Unknown column 'TrabajadasTrabajadasEnHoras' in 'field list'

Comment: el motivo de que no funcione creo que es por la versión que utilizo. Por ejemplo, en dicha versión DATEDIFF no funciona solo TIMESTAMPDIFF ...

Comment: Si claro. ¿Que motor de DB estas utilizando y cual version del mismo ?

Comment: Tipo de servidor: MySQL
Versión del servidor: 5.7.32, for Linux